# Google Mini only serving linking pages

Tags: search, google-search-appliance

I have a peculiar error in our Google Mini box. The setup is as simple as it can be.

- Google Mini is set to crawl a specific site and only that site.
- We have only the default front-end and default-collection
- No page exceptions or exclusions
- No https or logins
- All Url's and ip adresses are correct.

Google Mini is crawling fine and indexing but when I use the test center search I don't get any results.

Update:

I can see and drill down to single pages threw the admin gui, e.g. the index contains over 4000 pages. 
The only results I can get is when I search for a specific page that links to another page, like so:

```
link http://example.com/page_that_links_to_searched_page.aspx
```

Does any one have an idea of why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Can you view cached pages through the Crawl Diagnostics page?

Comment: Yess, I can drill down from the root node down to a single page. There I can see the cached page, ranking and all.

Comment: And do you get zero results if you search the default collection for something general like 'com' or 'aspx'?